# Disable one side of the sound

Tags: audio, video

I want to make a video clip with some old videos I downloaded from YouTube.
The problem with these old videos is that one side of the earphone makes shrill noises.
Is there a way to edit that videos and disable the annoying side?

Comment: What video editing software do you use?

Comment: Basically I use the windows movie maker. But I can get any software if you know a software that can do it

Comment: Then I would recommend using Audacity to [extract the audio](http://www.guidingtech.com/12836/extract-audio-from-video-audacity/) and then using Audacity again to mute one side. [This page](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/splitting_and_joining_stereo_tracks.html) may help with that.